change colouur of background button in json formatting
I'm doing some filtering on 2 webparts.
Below is the firet webpart that filters based on the letter A,B etc..
When click is it possible to set the background colour to a colour (For exampleto the colour of the selected checked box

See current code below:
"children": [
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },

Any tip or resources would be appreciated

To change the background color of a button in JSON formatting, you can define a custom JSON template for the button and use the "style" property to set the background color. Here's an example JSON template that sets the background color to red when the button is clicked:
{
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Click me",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "defaultClick",
    "style": {
      "background-color": "red"
    }
  }
}


THanks Xyza_MSFT. Tried it ut doesn't work
